# Jquery: Select the second td of tr element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i will select the closest tr and save it to a variable

```
var closestElement = $(this).closest('tr');
```

later in some part i need to get the 2nd td of this element and want replace the text with 
my own text .

How can i do it in jquery ?

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, so where are you stuck???

Comment: The jquery docs are very readable and browsable; I encourage you to use them first when trying to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
closestElement.children(':eq(1)').text('your own text');
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(closestElement).find("td:eq(1)").text("your text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var closestElement = $(this).closest('tr');

     closestElement.find("td:eq(1").text("desire text");
```

in single line you can do by following way.

```js
    $(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)").text("desire text");
```

reference **[eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**